# App compilations in centos crystal obtain error

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the following code:

```
require "kemal"



get "/" do
  "Hello Kemal!"
end

Kemal.run
```

But when I'm going to launch the application in centos it tells me the following:

```
crystal run app

/usr/bin/ld: it can not be found -lz
/usr/bin/ld: it can not be found -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: it can not be found-lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: it can not be found-lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned the exit statusa 1
Error: execution of command failed with code: 1: `cc "${@}" -o '/root/.cache/crystal/crystal-run-aplicacion.tmp'  -rdynamic  -lz `command -v pkg-config > /dev/null && pkg-config --libs --silence-errors libssl || printf %s '-lssl -lcrypto'` `command -v pkg-config > /dev/null && pkg-config --libs --silence-errors libcrypto || printf %s '-lcrypto'` -lpcre -lm /usr/bin/../lib/crystal/lib/libgc.a -lpthread /usr/share/crystal/src/ext/libcrystal.a -levent -lrt -ldl -L/usr/bin/../lib/crystal/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib`
```

someone knows what happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missing the some libraries. Read this articles:

- https://crystal-lang.org/reference/installation/
- https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/All-required-libraries

How did you install Crystal?